# Connecting ControllerBase.User with database user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have several APIs with authentication. I would like to provide authorization as well. To do this I need to get user information from the database user table. What is the correct way to connect the ControllerBase.User and the user in the database?

1. I could add claims but what bothers me is that to my limited knowledge they are string based. One of the claims I would filter on a lot would be an integer Id. This means that every time I use it I have to cast the claim to an integer? That doesn't seem right.
2. Or is there a way to extend the ControllerBase.User with properties of my choosing and use those properties in every controller? I could fill those properties using middleware.
3. ?

Comment: what kind of authentication is it? windows, jwt, identity or custom?

Comment: @AntonToshik OpenID Connect uses JWT.